# How to change NaN string representation in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, tostring, nan

My program saves a pointcloud to file, where each pointcloud is a `Point3D[,]`, from the `System.Windows.Media.Media3D` namespace. This shows a line of the output file (in portuguese):

```
-112,644088741971;71,796623005014;NaN (Não é um número)
```

while I'd like it to be (on order to be correctly parsed afterwards):

```
-112,644088741971;71,796623005014;NaN
```

The block of code that generates the file is here:

```
var lines = new List<string>();

for (int rows = 0; rows < malha.GetLength(0); rows++) {
    for (int cols = 0; cols < malha.GetLength(1); cols++) {

        double x = coordenadas_x[cols];
        double y = coordenadas_y[rows];
        double z;

        if ( SomeTest() ) {
            z = alglib.rbfcalc2(model, x, y);
        } else {
            z = double.NaN;
        }

        var p = new Point3D(x, y, z);
        lines.Add(p.ToString());                       

        malha[rows, cols] = p;
    }
}

File.WriteAllLines("../../../../dummydata/malha.txt", lines);
```

It seems like the `double.NaN.ToString()` method, called from inside `Point3D.ToString()`, includes that parenthesized "additional explanation" which I don't want at all.

Is there a way to change/override this method so that it outputs only `NaN`, without the parentheses part?

Comment: Take a look at NumberFormatInfo.NaNSymbol (the notes section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: @daniloquio Do you think you could provide a quick working code with your suggestion? I'm pretty sure that what I was looking for!

Comment: edited my current answer with a solution. Please take a look

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Double.ToString()` uses `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` to format its numbers. This last property references to the `CultureInfo` that is currently set on the active thread. This defaults to the user's current locale. In this case its a Portuguese culture setting. To avoid this behavior, use the `Double.ToString(IFormatProvider)` overload. In this case you could use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Additionally you can just switch the NaN symbol if you want to retain all other markup. By default globalization information is read only. Creating a clone will get around this.

```
System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = 
    (System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo) System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
numberFormatInfo.NaNSymbol = "NaN";

double num = double.NaN;
string numString = System.Number.FormatDouble(num, null, numberFormatInfo);
```

To set this on the current thread, create a copy of the current culture and set the number format info on the culture. [Pre .NET 4.5](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/39ab12ba-283e-4f82-945a-18f30d1366b0) there's no way to set it for all threads. After creating each thread you would have to ensure a correct `CultureInfo`. As of .NET 4.5 there's `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` which defines the default culture for threads within the `AppDomain`. This setting is only considered when the culture of the thread has not been set yet (see MSDN).

Example for a single thread:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo myCulture =
     (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
myCulture.NumberFormat.NaNSymbol = "NaN";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = myCulture;   
string numString = double.NaN.ToString();
```

Comment: That won't produce his desired output, which uses a localized decimal separator.

Comment: Currently I get the string `NaN (não é um número)`. My goal is not to get `NaN (not a number)` but instead only the plain `NaN`. How could I get this?

Comment: According to Daniloquio comment, there is the `NumberFormatInfo.NaNSymbol` property, that "Gets or sets the string that represents the IEEE NaN (not a number) value." So my question would boil down to "how can I set the NaNSymbol of my current thread's culture?"

Comment: @heltonbiker: You want to change this globally for your entire program, or just for formatting `Point3D` inside this loop?

Comment: Ideally it would be the whole program, because it would be a more general, powerful, and "right" solution in my opinion. I'd rather have a program that produces strings the way I want than having to go around reformatting arbitrary outputs.

Comment: I'll go with the culture-for-the-current-thread approach, but for the record, I tested the `output.Replace(System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NaNSymbol, "NaN")` and it worked fine. A nice quick-n-dirty trick to have around!

Comment: +1 Edited with some minor corrections to the implementation. I tested it and I can say it works like a charm.

Comment: Yeah don't clobber the thread's culture unless you are going to restore it after.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't pass NaN values to `ToString`.

For example (wrapping in an extension method for easy reuse):

```
static string ToCleanString(this double val)
{
    if (double.IsNan(val)) return "NaN";
    return val.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I updated my code. Actually `double.NaN.ToString()` method is being called from inside `Point3D.ToString()` method...

Comment: @heltonbiker: Yeah, I wondered about that.  And it changes things.  I think my preference would be just to replace the `Point3D.ToString()` call with my own method that converts and concatenates all three values under my control.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
NumberFormatInfo myFormatInfo = NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;

Point3D myPoint = new Point3D(1,1,double.NaN);
var pointString = myPoint.ToString(myFormatInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the answer provided by Caramiriel is the solution to have `double.NaN` represented by ANY string you might desire.

Incidentally, I want the string `"NaN"`, and here is what [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.nansymbol.aspx) say about `NumberFormatInfo.NaNSymbol`:

> The string that represents the IEEE NaN (not a number) value. The default for InvariantInfo is "NaN".

Then I figured how to have my desired pure "NaN" string AND get rid of the comma separator, by using the default provided by `InvariantCultureInfo`, adding the folloing line just after the current thread is created:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

And that worked fine!