# Change default NaN representation of fprintf() in Matlab

Tags: matlab, printf

I am trying to export data from Matlab in format that would be understood by another application... For that I need to change the `NaN`, `Inf` and `-Inf` strings (that Matlab prints by default for such values) to `//m`, `//inf+` and `//Inf-`.

In general I DO KNOW how to accomplish this. I am asking how (and whether it is possible) to exploit one particular thing in Matlab. The actual question is located in the last paragraph.

There are two approaches that I have attempted (code bellow).

1. Use `sprintf()` on *data* and `strrep()` the output. This is done in line-by-line fashion in order to save memory. This solution takes almost 10 times more time than simple `fprintf()`. The advantage is that it has low memory overhead.
2. Same as option **1.**, but the translation is done on the whole *data* at once. This solution is way faster, but vulnerable to out of memory exception. My problem with this approach is that I do not want to unnecessarily duplicate the *data*.

### Code:

> ```
> rows = 50000  
> cols = 40  
> data = rand(rows, cols); % generate random matrix  
> data([1 3 8]) = NaN; % insert some NaN values  
> data([5 6 14]) = Inf; % insert some Inf values  
> data([4 2 12]) = -Inf; % insert some -Inf values  
>
> fid = fopen('data.txt', 'w'); %output file  
>
> %% 0) Write data using default fprintf  
> format = repmat('%g ', 1, cols);  
>
> tic  
> fprintf(fid, [format '\n'], data');  
> toc  
>
> %% 1) Using strrep, writing line by line  
> fprintf(fid, '\n');  
> tic  
> for i = 1:rows  
>     fprintf(fid, '%s\n', strrep(strrep(strrep(sprintf(format, data(i, :)), 'NaN', '//m'), '-Inf', '//inf-'), 'Inf', '//inf+'));  
> end  
> toc  
>
> %% 2) Using strrep, writing all at once  
> fprintf(fid, '\n');  
> format = [format '\n'];  
> tic  
>     fprintf(fid, '%s\n', strrep(strrep(strrep(sprintf(format, data'), 'NaN', '//m'), '-Inf', '//inf-'), 'Inf', '//inf+'));  
> toc
> ```

### Output:

> Elapsed time is 1.651089 seconds. % Regular fprintf()
>   Elapsed time is 11.529552 seconds. % Option 1
>   Elapsed time is 2.305582 seconds. % Option 2

**Now to the question...**

I am not satisfied with the memory overhead and time lost using my solutions in comparison with simple `fprintf()`.
My rationale is that the `'NaN'`, `'Inf'` and `'-Inf'` strings are simple data saved in some variable inside the `*printf()` or `*2str()` implementation. Is there any way to change their value at runtime?
For example in C# I would change the `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NaNSymbol`, etc. as explaind [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301101/how-to-change-nan-string-representation-in-c).

Comment: Why don't you replace these values while the data is in the MATLAB workspace and afterwards export the result? This should be much faster than replacing while exporting.

Comment: @EliDuenisch because, the data in workspace is saved as *double*. It would have to be *string* in order for me to apply the conversion a priori.

Comment: find the indices of NaNs etc., then convert your data to a cell array using num2cell, replace the indices by strings and export afterwards

Comment: @EliDuenisch I have tried that (and several other approaches) as well, perhaps you could check the edit history of my question, I did not write down all the things I tried for the sake of length... Converting the *data* to cell array is 1) slow (cca 70 seconds in the example) 2) memory heavy... I don't want to duplicate all my data, because we could be talking gigabytes.

Comment: The internal string conversion appears to head back to an undocumented built in helper function, `sprintfc`, which as far as I can tell is not alterable.  About the only thing that I'd suggest trying would be prechecking how many rows you have that contain one of these values using `~isfinite` and then rather than looping over every row, `fprintf` blocks of rows at a time where possible (but tbh I would probably give up at this point, dump the data to file and use a non-MATLAB method to manipulate the text file after the fact).

Comment: Of course there might be an undocumented feature to tweak the default strings and if you find something please share with us. As usual there is a trade-off between speed and memory: If you want to save memory you'll have to do the conversion chunk-wise which is slow.

Comment: As already suggested: If speed is the issue, do not use Matlab for the conversion. Perhaps you could use a command line tool like GNU sed.

Comment: @nkjt thanks, interesting note. My problem with the data is that if NaNs appear, there is full column of them -> that means that almost every row would have some. I am unable to learn much about the `sprintfc` function, but it appears to me that rather the `num2str` function (or some of it's sister) is responsible. Am I mistaken? Please do correct me. Could this be version specific?

Comment: @Hugo the speed is an issue, but using sed (especially on widows:) will cause all kinds of portability problems... mainly because I am not going to be the one actually running the script in the first place. Also the Matlab versions widely differ amongst computers that will run the script. And installing some other package (sed, or rather coreutils) on all of them is out of the question as well. So far it seems that I will have to stick to my older solution... thx everyone anyway.

Comment: @Kupto - `num2str` code is readable (`edit num2str`) but the actual conversion doesn't seem to happen directly in that code but when `num2str` calls `sprintfc` - you won't find a help file for it, it's undocumented and a builtin (so you can't edit it or see what the code is doing).  Question - is it definite that if NaN/Inf/-Inf  appear there is a full column of them? If so, there is another option based on my deep love of abusing string formats, but I'm not sure if it would be quicker.

Comment: @nkjt Yes indeed... Now I can find the `sprintfc` I have not noticed it inside the `num2str` before. But the enclosing function (`cellPrintf()` and hence the `sprintfc()` also) never seems to get triggered. On other hand, it seems that the `fprintf` function gets used. Answer - yes it is sure... what algorithm do you have on mind? sounds interesting. Just to let you know, I have tried setting the format to fixed width and seeking inside the file afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

In the limited case mentioned in comments that a number of (unknown, changing per data set) columns may be entirely `NaN` (or `Inf`, etc), but that there are not unwanted `NaN` values otherwise, another possibility is to check the first row of data, assemble a format string which writes the `\\m` strings directly, and use that while telling `fprintf` to ignore the columns that contain `NaN` or other unwanted values.

```
y = ~isnan(data(1,:)); % find all non-NaN
format = sprintf('%d ',y); % print a 1/0 string
format = strrep(format,'1','%g'); 
format = strrep(format,'0','//m'); 

fid = fopen('data.txt', 'w'); 
fprintf(fid, [format '\n'], data(:,y)'); %pass only the non-NaN data
fclose(fid);
```

By my check with two columns of `NaN` this `fprintf` is pretty much the same as your "regular" `fprintf` and quicker than the loop - not taking into account the initialisation step of producing `format`.  It would be fiddlier to set it up to automatically produce the format string if you also have to take +/- `Inf` into account, but certainly possible.  There is probably a cleaner way of producing `format` as well.

How it works:

You can pass in a subset of your data, and you can also insert any text you like into a format string, so if every row has the same desired "text" in the same spot (in this case `NaN` columns and our desired replacement for "NaN"), we can put the text we want in that spot and then just not pass those parts of the data to `fprintf` in the first place.  A simpler example for trying out on the command line:

```
x = magic(5);
x(:,3)=NaN
sprintf('%d %d ihatethrees %d %d \n',x(:,[1,2,4,5])');
```

Comment: +1 for improving the performance of my code, this is a nice spin to one thing I have tried and I think that it will actually work much smoother now... however it does not solve the question whether it is possible to change the default string for NaN (so I can't green-tick it)... nevertheless after much other searching my fear is that the correct answer to OP is plain: "NO" =( thanks very much anyway nkjt.