# String.Format(new CultureInfo("el-GR"), "{0:#,,0.00}", value) change output to 0 if value=NaN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible in the following line 
`<td>@String.Format(new CultureInfo("el-GR"), "{0:#,,0.00}", value)</td>`
to manipulate the output, so if value is NaN or infinity to return 0?

Thanks in advance for any help.
Regards

Comment: Yes and no... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301101/how-to-change-nan-string-representation-in-c You can modify the string representation of NaN and +-Infinity, but you'll set it to a string value, so like "0" that won't be formatted to 0.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I won't judge on the goodness/badness of what you want to do here**

From [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings):

> Regardless of the format string, if the value of a Single or Double floating-point type is positive infinity, negative infinity, or not a number (NaN), the formatted string is the value of the respective PositiveInfinitySymbol, NegativeInfinitySymbol, or NaNSymbol property specified by the currently applicable NumberFormatInfo object.

So as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301101/how-to-change-nan-string-representation-in-c) you could reconfigure your `CultureInfo` to have whatever string representation of `NaN`, `PositiveInfinity`, `NegativeInfinity` you want, but note that they are `string` values, so they won't format to `0,00`. You can clearly set their string value to to `0,00` (`"0,00"` *is* a legal `string` value), like this:

```
public static readonly CultureInfo GreekCultureInfoWithoutNanInfinity0dot00 = CreateCultureInfoWithoutNanInfinity("gr-GR", "0.00");

private static CultureInfo CreateCultureInfoWithoutNanInfinity(string name, string format)
{
    var ci = new CultureInfo(name);

    string num = (0d).ToString(format, ci);

    ci.NumberFormat.PositiveInfinitySymbol = num;
    ci.NumberFormat.NegativeInfinitySymbol = num;
    ci.NumberFormat.NaNSymbol = num;

    return ci;
}
```

and then use the `GreekCultureInfoWithoutNanInfinity0dot00` as the culture when you want to format numbers in Greek format `"0.00"`,

Or perhaps you could directly create a new

```
public static string FormatNoNaN(IFormatProvider provider, string format, double obj1)
```

where you handle the "special cases" of `NaN`, `PositiveInfinity`, `NegativeInfinity`.